# Bootstrap + Chrome Issue, highlighting elements changes bg color

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I'm getting weird background artifacts in Chrome when I hover or highlight over objects.  This doesn't happen for me in Safari or Firefox.

http://charleslawportfolio.com/new/

No idea what's happening, but it only occurs if I include my buttons in the footer.  If I remove those buttons, this issue doesn't exist anymore.

I'm using Bootstrap, but I've looked over the code countless times and can't figure it out.

Here's an image of the issue
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3MOk.png

Any leads would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm not experiencing your issue when I go to your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is missing a DOCTYPE, which is required for proper display;

> Requires HTML5 doctype
>
> Bootstrap makes use of certain HTML elements and CSS properties that
>   require the use of the HTML5 doctype. Include it at the beginning of
>   all your projects.

From the [docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html).

Also, make sure to validate, your page is riddled with repeated ids.

Comment: Fixed a bunch of stuff, problem no longer exists.  Thanks!